# Raphael, get elements angle after transform

Tags: raphael, transform, angle

As is displayed here: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

Raphael's transform allows me to move the element, but without changing the element's attributes.

But as is explained here: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/raphaeljs/126j03p95c/get-x-y-coordinates-after-transformation it is possible to get a rectangle's post transformation x and y values.
But what I can't figure out is how to get post-transformation *angle* of the rectangle.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access the matrix object of the element and invoke the method split() to get an object returned with a set of information about the matrix transformation. Check the property "rotate" in the object to get the rotational state of the element in degrees.

```
var R = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 400),
    rect = R.rect(0, 0, 100, 100).transform("r45");
console.log(rect.matrix.split().rotate);
```

Refer http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Matrix.split

Hope this helps.